# Redirect to specific page if localstorage value not found in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router, higher-order-components

I am using reactjs.

I have multiple following routes in my index.js file

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <App>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/Login" component={SignIn} />
          <Route exact path="/Sign-up" component={SignUp} />
          <Route exact path="/Orders" component={Orders} />
          <Route exact path="/Category" component={Category} />
          <Route exact path="/Shops" component={Shops} />
        </Switch>
      </App>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

initially when user goes to base URL suppose
**Http://localhost:3000**

he should be redirected to
**Http://localhost:3000/Shops** page if value of localstorage item is null

and also if user tries to visit other pages he should be redirected to the **/Shops** page.

One way of doing this is using HOC but further i'll be adding auth soo there i'll have to wrap the component in route with HOC like this

```
<Route exact path="/Orders" component={AuthGuard(Orders)} />
```

I dont know whether I can do like this

```
<Route exact path="/Orders" component={AuthGuard, ShopGuard(Orders)} />
```

soo how can i achieve this without using HOC or how can I wrap 2 HOC for a single component.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use nested HOCs `HOC1(HOC2(HOC3(Component)))` or you can use libraries like `Compose` from `Redux` to compose multiple HOC for single component

Comment: then further how should I use it ? @Sabesh

Comment: You should be able to wrap the HOC while exporting your component like,
`export default ShopGuard(AuthGuard(Orders)))`

Comment: Nesting HOCs could help/work, but I wouldn't recommend in-lining them where you're trying to use components; the component exports should be the already-decorated components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function HandleRedirection() {
    const RedirectToShop = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
        return (
            <Route
                {...rest}
                render={(props) =>
                    localStorage.getItem('user') ? (
                        <App>
                            <Component {...props} />
                        </App>
                    ) : (
                            <Redirect to="/shop" />
                        )}
            />
        );
    };
    return (
                <BrowserRouter basename={`/`}>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path={`/shop`} component={Shops} />
                            <RedirectToShop exact path={`/login`} component={Signin} />
                            <RedirectToShop exact path={`/order`} component={Order} />
                            <RedirectToShop exact path={`/category`} component={Category} />
                            <Redirect to="/shop" />
                        </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

Comment: Should I write HandleRedirection() function is another file ?

Comment: Yes. or You can directly write this code in Your index.js route file.

Comment: Yes it did work.
but further If I want to add another condition to route how should I do it.

Comment: Which condition ? and Please mark this answer right if it is correct.,

Comment: currently I am using your above given code to check if latitude and longitude are present in localstorage or not, If they are not I am redirecting user to **baseURL/Shops** page.

further I will be adding authentication too.
Soo how do I manage to do that into this.

Comment: There i'll be adding condition to check the token in localstorage.

Comment: <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) =>
                localStorage.getItem('latlong') ? (
                    <App>
                        <Component {...props} />
                    </App>
                ) : (                 localStorage.getItem('userAuthentication') ? (
                        <Redirect to="/shop" /> ) : (  <Redirect to="/login" /> )
                    )}
        />

Comment: Working perfectly, thank you @AnjaliChandwani

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom `Route` component that can check localStorage and redirect to "/shop" if condition is (*or isn't?*) met.

```
const ShopGuardRoute = ({ component: Component, ...props }) => (
  <Route
    {...props}
    render={routeProps => {
      const item = localStorage.getItem("key");
      
      // Do all your conditional tests here
      return item !== null ? (
        <Component {...routeProps} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/shop" />
      );
    }}
  />
);
```

Usage

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <App>
    <Switch>
      <ShopGuardRoute path="/Login" component={SignIn} />
      <ShopGuardRoute path="/Sign-up" component={SignUp} />
      <ShopGuardRoute path="/Orders" component={Orders} />
      <ShopGuardRoute path="/Category" component={Category} />
      <Route path="/Shops" component={Shops} />
      <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    </Switch>
  </App>
</BrowserRouter>
```

[image: Edit ShopGuardRoute]

If you plan on adding an authentication check then [auth-workflow](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow) may help.

Comment: @SagarChavan Are there any errors, or is it simply just not working as expected? I'll try getting a working codesandbox up as admittedly I only wrote this based on common custom route component patterns.

Comment: @SagarChavan Redirect worked out the box for me, but wanted to test the localStorage logic as well. I did notice you TitleCase your paths where normally they would be lowercased, so maybe that was the issue, the path didn't match if you copy/pasted, i.e. `"/Shops" !== "/shops"` when it comes to path matching. I updated my answer with a running codesandbox.

Comment: i'll give it a try.

Comment: @SagarChavan Updated with added comments about additional conditional tests and auth flow based on your questions/comments elsewhere in this SO post.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can just do something like this on all the required pages `if(condition // your local storage null check) { history.push(`/yourPath`, dataIfAny); }`